# why wont the echo show?

Tags: php, mysqli

The following code will run the `$users->vote` but won’t run the `echo` or set the cookie.

```
if(isset($_POST['confirmation']) and $_POST['confirmation']== true )
{
//We add the vote
    if($users->vote($id))
{
    echo '<strong>Your vote has successfully been recorded.</strong>';
//set a 24 hr cookie
    setcookie('topsitevoste', time()+43200);
    }
}
else{
```

The function for `$users->vote` is:

```
public function vote ($id){

        $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE ID = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have been fiddling with this code for 2 hours to no avail, I was beginning to think that maybe the `$query` was causing a crash when run but I can not for the life of me work out why.

Comment: After `$query->execute();` add echo `mysql_error();` to see if it's something wrong with query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `vote()` function never returns anything, so it cannot possibly return `true` for the if() condition to evaluate as true.

You could probably just add `return` in front of `$query->execute();` since it returns a boolean.

Furthermore, it needs to be `$users->vote($id)`, `$users->vote` would attempt to get the property `$vote` on the users object, so that may be causing it to fail as well.

Comment: thank you, literally putting return in in front of $query->execute(); solved the issue, big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up & properly formatting code can help you debug. In this you initially call `$users->vote` but not as a function connected to a class like this `$users->vote()`. If you call just `$users->vote` that refers to a variable. The `$users->vote()` calls the function `vote()` that is part of a larger class instantiated as `$users`:

```
if (isset($_POST['confirmation']) and $_POST['confirmation'] == 'true') {
    //We add the vote
    if ($users->vote($id)) {
      echo '<strong>Your vote has successfully been recorded.</strong>';
      //set a 24 hr cookie
      setcookie('topsitevoste', time()+43200);
    }
}
else {
```

Also, what does `$_POST['confirmation'] == 'true'` actually check? Are you checking for the word `true` or the value being `true`?  Perhaps that should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['confirmation']) and $_POST['confirmation'] == true) {
```

But what does `vote()` do (as called by `$users->vote()`)other than run a MySQL query?

```
public function vote ($id){
  $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE ID = ?");
  $query->bindValue(1, $id);

  try {
    $query->execute();
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
   }
}
```

So you should perhaps refactor like so to return a `true` or `false` based on what happens in the `try`/`catch` check:

```
public function vote ($id){
  $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE ID = ?");
  $query->bindValue(1, $id);

  try {
    $query->execute();
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Being pedantic: pass some id for argument in function too.

Comment: ($user->vote($id)) literally just runs the query, which is in a separate page, sorry for not saying so. the real problem is that as soon as it executes the query nothing else fires up, as you say it is probably the fact there is no true or false but i cant understand how to put one in.

Comment: Thank you all for helping with the syntax errors and other bits and pieces i had missed.